# How to click through layout?

Tags: android, constraints, clickable

I have two dialog fragments: dialog1 and dialog2 which is behind first one.When a user clicks on dialog1 I want to consume onClick from dialog2.Right now I need to click twice on dialog1 to get to dialog2 and then to click on the button that I wanted to do with the first click.

Is it possible with XML attributes focusable and clickable?

I've created a helper class for creating dialog fragments, and here is just one part of it:

```
 public void showDialog2 {
        final TutorialDialog messageDialog = TutorialDialog.newInstance();
      messageDialog.setTitle("How cool! You just copied a pro trader!")
          .setDescription("Let's proceed.")
          .setNegativeButtonText("Skip tutorial")
          .setPositiveButtonText("Let's proceed")
          .setOnNegativeButtonClickListener(new TutorialDialog.OnNegativeButtonClickListener() {
            @Override public void onNegativeButtonClick() {
              messageDialog.dismiss();
            }
          })
          .setOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new TutorialDialog.OnPositiveButtonClickListener() {
            @Override public void onPositiveButtonClick() {
              // TODO: 8/29/17 call next dialog
              messageDialog.dismiss();
              onContinueButtonClick();
            }
          });

        messageDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "confirmation_tutorial_dialog");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using two fragments just use one because, you just want onClick on second fragment

Comment: Coz I'm showing tutorial for users and need to use on top of another

Comment: But if you want click event on second fragment then what the use of first fragment direct show all information on second fragment

Comment: I'm using second dialog for showing how to use app, first one got real data and I want it to be clickable

Answer (score 0):

as I know the clickable attribute just is about some options like onClickListener() and etc.
you also can use cancelable on dialog builder design pattern to dismiss.
but a good way for tutorial messaging is using the libraries on the net.